# Как реализовать систему лайков на сайте?

Tags: база-данных, like

Как реализовать систему лайков на сайте, чтобы видео с большим количеством лайков было выше чем то у которого меньше?Мне нужна бд или можно обойтись и без нее, вроде, она уменьшает безопасность сайта?всем, спасибо, кто ответил.

Comment: Без бд никак не обойтись и она сама по себе не влияет на безопасность сайта

Comment: а как же там майэскэль инъекции майэсклюэль же для бд

Comment: Чтобы не был sql-инъекций, запросы в базу не вручную составляются, а через связывание параметров (binding), например не `sql("select * from table where user='" + user + "'")`, а `sql("select * from table where user=?", user)`, тогда вместо `?` будет подставлено экранированное значение, что исключит sql-инъекцию

Comment: @gil9red Жалко нельзя комменты в избранное...